# CSS :before content two colors

Tags: css, xml, html, semantic-markup

I have a structured semantic data that I would like to display, styling it with CSS. Here is a sample:

```
...<user name="John">...</user>...
```

I would like it to be rendered like this:

```
...
User John ...
...
```

If I wanted 'User' and 'John' to have the same color, I could use the following CSS:

```
user:before{
  content: 'User ' attr(name);
}
```

However, I want 'User' to be blue, and 'John' to be red. How can I achieve this with CSS?

P.S. I don't want to transform my data representation. I know I could easily get such formatting by transforming the data to have extra divs, etc, but I would like to display my pure semantic data directly in the form it is.

Comment: Are you trying to style an XML document?

Comment: content: '<name>User</name>' attr(name); name {color: different;}

Comment: not sure if it will work but that's what i would try

Comment: Can't have HTML in `content:` (or more accurately, it won't render as HTML).

Comment: @KevinBoucher: I didn't say on purpose whether it's XML or HTML, because it's a question about CSS that applies to both.

Comment: It'd have taken him a few second to test its idea in jsfiddle/codepen/dabblet

Comment: @user: There are plenty of discussions on meta regarding answering in comments; see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4217/why-do-some-people-answer-in-comments which would seem most relevant here.

Answer (score 6):

If the `user` element is empty, you could use the following CSS:

```
user::before {content:"User "; color:blue;}
user::after {content:attr(name); color:red;}
```

If the `user` element contains content, you may use:

```
user::before {content:"User "; color:blue; float:left; margin-right:0.5em;}
user::after {content:attr(name); color:red; float:left; margin-right:0.5em;}
```

(using `float` to get the element content behind the "User John" string; using `margin` to get whitespace between the words; there are probably neater ways to fix those things)

Answer (score 2):

You can't style *part* of content of `:before` pseudo differently in CSS. You need an extra element (like a `span`) somewhere. `:first-letter` and `:first-line` (and content of `:before` as a whole) are exceptions to that but that's not what you want to achieve.