# html label:after content needs to have different colors in the text

Tags: html, css, pseudo-class

I have the display name of my model properties set, but I need them to display with a colon if they're not required and a colon and a red asterisk if they are.

I didn't want to add the colon to the display name since I don't want the colon to appear in error messages and I may want to display them somewhere without it.

I used the following style in my HTML file for adding the colon:

```css
.my-label > label:after {
        content: ": ";
}
```

However I can't figure out how to get a red asterisk to display after that if the field is required.

I could create another style class to include the asterisk, however if I change the color it's either all red or all black. I'm not sure I want to set the actual model property to be required because I'm not sure I want a universal rule stating that it is required.

Any suggestions of a better way to handle this would be welcome.

Comment: What do you mean by *if they are not required*? Do you mean that the corresponding `input` doesn't have the `required` attribute?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS :before content two colors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14288847/css-before-content-two-colors) - before vs. after doesn't matter. Unfortunately there is no direct solution.

Comment: Can you give us your html too?

Comment: The particular page I'm working on is a use case that requires input into some of the fields.  Some fields are required on this page, others are not.  But other use cases may not require that input so I don't want to set the actual model field to be required.  Is that what you were asking?

Comment: I am not sure I understood you but as mentioned in an earlier comment, it would be good if you show us your HTML (and indicate particularly how a required field is differentiated from the rest).

Comment: I believe I understand what OP wants to do. She has 2 types of labels (for an input field for example) where some might be required fields while others optional. For the optional the `:after` should have `content: ": "` but for the required fields `content: ": *"`. Here's the catch though - I believe the asterisk needs to be red but the colon black. --- sadly, I don't think this is possible without altering html. Why not just add the `:` to the label itself?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## The problem

It is not possible to use different colours in a single pseudo element. In this case you are able to output `:*` using the `:after` pseudo element but are not able to make the characters different colours.

## Solution 1

One possible way to achieve what you are after is to use the `:before` pseudo element. The overriding issue, of course is that this will put the asterisk at the beginning of the `label`. You can fix this by making the `label` use the flexbox model. This will allow the order of the pseudo elements to be changed allowing you to place the `:before` element at the end of the `label`:

```css
.my-label > label {
  display: inline-flex;
}
.my-label.required > label:before {
  color: red;
  content: "*";
  order: 1;
}
.my-label > label:after {
  content: ":";
}
```

```html
<div class="my-label">
  <label>Not required</label>
  <input type="text" />
</div>
<div class="my-label required">
  <label>Required</label>
  <input type="text" />
</div>
```

## The drawbacks

The drawbacks to this solution is that if the user is using a browser that does not support flexbox or IE ([where a bug stops the flexbox rules being applied to pseudo elements](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#12-inline-elements-are-not-treated-as-flex-items)) the asterisk will be displayed before the label.

## Solution 2

A second way to achieve this would be to use absolute positioning. By setting `label` to `position: relative;` you can position the `:before` element at its end by making it `position: absolute;` and `right: 0;`. By adding some right `padding` you can "reserve" space for the element so the text doesn't overlap.

```css
.my-label > label {
  /*10px is for old browsers which don't support the ch unit*/
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-right: 1ch;
  position: relative;
}
.my-label.required > label:before {
  color: red;
  content: "*";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
.my-label > label:after {
  content: ":";
}
```

```html
<div class="my-label">
  <label>Not required</label>
  <input type="text" />
</div>
<div class="my-label required">
  <label>Required</label>
  <input type="text" />
</div>
```

## The drawbacks

Not many drawbacks to this method as it should work in the majority of browsers (even older ones).

Comment: I ended up doing something similar to this.  I created a simple label after the "LabelFor" that I used for the display name of the model.  That label contained a red asterisk.  I put those two inside a flexbox and it seems to be working just fine.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

As said in comments  why you don't  just add the `:` to the `label` itself, since it belongs to content?

Then you can have a simple `::after` with the `color:red`

Why complicate, when the things are simple.

```css
.required::after {
  color: red;
  content: "*";
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>Not required:</label>
  <input type="text" />
  <label class="required">Required:</label>
  <input type="text" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the markup suggested by Hidden Hobbes, as an alternative to flexbox, you can use a combination of relative and absolute positioning to place the asterisk in the desired location.

This approach may require some adjustment to get the horizontal and vertical placement just right for the font in use.

```css
.my-label > label {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.my-label.required > label {
  padding-right: 1em;
}
.my-label.required > label:before {
  color: red;
  content: "*";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.1em;
  right: 0.25em;
}
.my-label > label:after {
  content: ":";
}
```

```html
<div class="my-label">
  <label>Not required</label>
  <input type="text" />
</div>
<div class="my-label required">
  <label>Required</label>
  <input type="text" />
</div>
```