# Multiple coloured text in input field

Tags: html, css

I have a simple input field that looks like:

```
<input class="input" id="name" type="text" name="name" value="* Your Name" onfocus="if (this.value == '* Your Name') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = '* Your Name';}">
```

I would like to have the *** Your Name** in two colours.
Something like:

```
<style>
.input {color: black}
.input span {color: red}
</style>

<input class="input" value="<span>*</span> Your Name">
```

Clearly the above code won't work. But I am just wondering what the best approach would be to solve this dilemma.  I genuinely don't even know if it's possible.

Comment: look at this, was also asking about this, and this is what i got , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37393323/change-a-part-of-the-text-placeholders-color

Comment: this can point you some direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37211597/html-labelafter-content-needs-to-have-different-colors-in-the-text

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change a part of the text placeholders color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37393323/change-a-part-of-the-text-placeholders-color)